# how to resolve a proxy class in Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, wcf, castle-windsor, wcffacility

I have a WCF service that I'm trying to resolve using Castle Windsor.  The registration used to look like this:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IBatchDataService>()
.AsWcfClient(WCFEndpoint
.FromConfiguration("Internal.IBatchDataService"))
.LifestyeTransient())
```

Now I've created a proxy that lives in process. It exposes the same interface (IBatchDataService) and takes a reference to the WCF service as a constructor argument.  How do I set up this up in Windsor so that any other classes get resolved to use the proxy class but the proxy class resolves to the WCF service.  I have this right now:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IBatchDataService>()
.ImplementedBy<BatchDataServiceClient>());
```

which should resolve the new proxy class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<IBatchDataService>().AsWcfClient(WCFEndpoint.FromConfiguration("Internal.IBatchDataService")).LifestyeTransient().Named("wcfBatchDataService"),
    Component.For<IBatchDataService>().ImplementedBy<BatchDataServiceClient>().AsDefault().DependsOn(
        Dependency.OnComponent("constructorParameterName", "wcfBatchDataService")
)
```

Where constructorParameterName is the name of the IBatchDataService parameter on your constructor.
I've not run it in a compiler so please let me know if this works for you.

Kind regards,
Marwijn.

Answer (score 0):

It is simply a decorator pattern. Windsor support's it OOTB:

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<IBatchDataService>().
        ImplementedBy<BatchDataServiceClient>(),
    Component.For<IBatchDataService().
        AsWcfClient(WCFEndpoint.FromConfiguration("Internal.IBatchDataService")).
        LifestyleTransient());
```